# Accord d'un adjectif précédant plusieurs noms

Tags: adjectifs, accord, coordination

La règle que je connais et que j'ai retrouvée en menant mes recherches est que l'on accorde l'adjectif au masculin pour peu qu'au moins l'un des noms qu'il qualifie soit masculin.

> Des paons et des perruches bleus

Cependant, est-ce aussi le cas quand l'adjectif *précède* les noms ?

> Les différents emplois et longueurs du tiret
>
> Les différents longueurs et emplois du tiret

Je ne vois pas vraiment de raison pour que ça ne soit pas le cas mais j'aimerais en avoir le cœur net. La première phrase me paraît impeccable, mais la deuxième me gêne un peu, même si je la préfère à « les différentes longueurs et emplois du tiret ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je n’ai pas trouvé de règle spécifique à ce cas, mais je crois que c’est la même chose que l’adjectif soit antéposé ou postposé. Les deux exemples donnés sont corrects grammaticalement, mais le deuxième choque effectivement l’oreille !

[Cette grammaire](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/031.html) indique:

> Pour des raisons d’euphonie, on évite dans la mesure du possible (à l’écrit) de mettre le mot au féminin en contact avec l’adjectif masculin. Dans la phrase *Dans la pièce il y avait une chaise et un bureau verts*, on aurait pu dire *un bureau et une chaise verts*, qui est parfaitement grammatical, mais un peu déplaisant à l’oreille, parce que l’adjectif au masculin se trouve immédiatement à côté d’un nom au féminin.

Il serait peut-être temps d’améliorer un peu la règle et d’accorder au genre du nom le plus proche, tout simplement…

Comment: Pas d'accord avec la dernière remarque : « un bureau et une chaise vertes »  me paraît bien pire ...

Comment: @jlliagre: surtout que à l'oral cela a une signification différente.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En même temps, à l’oral, "une chaise et un bureau verts" peut aussi se comprendre de deux façons (la différence pouvant se faire par le rythme, s’il y a pause ou pas au niveau du “et”, si l’on “colle” plus ou moins l’adjectif à “bureau”…). Faudrait un genre neutre, là ! lol

Comment: @jilliagre Il y a une différence entre un mauvais choix de convention d'écriture et une pure erreur sur le fonctionnement de la langue. **vɛʁt** est la seule prononciation possible dans ce contexte, pas de **vɛʁ** ici.